# How to return a new Instance in php

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
class Email_Driver
{
   public function testEmail_Driver()
    {
       echo "testEmail_Driver".RT;
    }
}
    
class Email_Smtp extends Email_Driver
{
    public function testEmail_Smtp()
    {
       echo "testEmail_Smtp".RT;
    }
}

class Email
{
  public $instance;

  public function __construct()
  {
      $this->instance = new Email_Smtp();
      return $this->instance;
  }
}


$mail = new Email();
var_dump($mail);
$mail->testEmail_Smtp();      //Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Email::testEmail_Smtp()
$mail->testEmail_Driver();
```

How do I get access to methode testEmail_Smtp() and testEmail_Driver() in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning subsiduary classes to `$instance` so in order to make you code work you need to use that instance

```
<?php
    define('RT','<br />');
    
    class Email_Driver{
        public function testEmail_Driver(){
            echo "testEmail_Driver".RT;
        }
    }
        
    class Email_Smtp extends Email_Driver{
        public function testEmail_Smtp(){
           echo "testEmail_Smtp".RT;
        }
    }

    class Email{
      public $instance;
      public function __construct(){
          $this->instance = new Email_Smtp();
      }
    }


    $mail = new Email();

    printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r($mail,true));
    $mail->instance->testEmail_Smtp();      //Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Email::testEmail_Smtp()
    $mail->instance->testEmail_Driver();

?>
```

Which outputs:

```
Email Object
(
    [instance] => Email_Smtp Object
        (
        )

)
testEmail_Smtp
testEmail_Driver
```

Comment: I wouldn't use the generic name `instance` in this instance. What about `smtp`?

Comment: OK I understand. Can I also make direct a return new Email_Smtp(); in my Email class?

Answer (score 0):

The code below should be enough. Basically the class `Email` now acts exactly the same as class `Email_Smtp`:

```
class Email_Driver
{
   public function testEmail_Driver()
    {
       echo "testEmail_Driver".PHP_EOL;
    }
}
    
class Email_Smtp extends Email_Driver
{
    public function testEmail_Smtp()
    {
       echo "testEmail_Smtp".PHP_EOL;
    }
}

class Email extends Email_Smtp 
{
  // any more methods
}

$mail = new Email();
var_dump($mail);
$mail->testEmail_Smtp();      
$mail->testEmail_Driver();
```

Comment: Sorry that is not a solution for me. I shorten the class Email. The line  $this->instance = new Email_Smtp(); will be dynamic, so I can't simply extends my class.

Comment: @hamburger OK, I understand. I had to work with what you had given in your question.